# Spring MVC : Jsp file does not display data from the controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

This is my controller code

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/testMvc")
        public String testero(Model model ){ 
                        String nameClient="HENOCKE";
                    Long CodeClient=2L;
                    String Address="LONDO Street";  

        System.out.println("****End and outputting to Jsp page: ****");
        return "rs";

        }
```

And as you can see i want to display data to my jsp files and this is my jsp file:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" charset=UTF-8>
<title>Banque </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/CSS/style1.css">

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Date Loaded from My controller....</h2>

    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Name : </th> <th><c:out  value="${nameClient}"/></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th>id Client:  </th> <th> <c:out  value=" ${CodeClient}" /> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Adress client: </th> <th> <c:out value="${Address}" /></th>
    </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i output data to my jsp? here **rs** is the Name of my Jsp file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the attributes to the model.

```
String nameClient = "Whatever";
model.addAttribute("nameClient",nameClient);
```

Read this:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

You should create `ModelAndView` object to put values to view:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/testMvc")
    public ModelAndView testero(){ 
       ModelAndView mov = new ModelAndView("rs");

       mov.addAttribute("nameClient", "HENOCKE");
       mov.addAttribute("CodeClient", 2L);
       mov.addAttribute("Address", "LONDO Street");

       System.out.println("****End and outputting to Jsp page: ****");
       return mov;
    }
```